# How to create a regular expression to escape '*' when it is preceded by an alphabet or another '*' (but not preceded by a number)

Tags: regex

Example:

Original String --> 20* kg*m**2/s**2

Here I do not want to escape '*' preceded by 0 but escape all other '*'.

Thanks,
Amit

Comment: Are you talking about conditionally escaping a character in a regex (which isn't possible), or dynamically creating a regex? If the latter, specify the language and show us your attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not specify what type of regular expression you are using and how you want to escape the asterisks. I assume you use PCRE and want to put a backslash in front of '*':

- Search `(?<![0-9])\*`
- Replace `\\*`

[Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/GDFloR/1/)

Comment: Thank you Alex! I tried following -  "((?<![0-9])[*])"

Alternatively, we can use following as well – 
"(?<=[\\D])([\\\\*])"